# Reduce execution time (pow function)

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity

I want to implement the following [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Senv.jpg) in code but I am not able to because of exceeding time limit, Can anyone help me reduce the execution time?

I tried using this in c++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){
    int n;
    long long ans = 0;
    std::cin >> n;
    for(int i=n-1; i>0;--i){
        ans += -pow(-1.0,(n-i))*pow(3.0,i);
    }
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

ps: This formula is for the following problem:https://codeforces.com/contest/166/problem/E

Comment: First, do not use that `<bits...>` header, as it is not standard.  Second, what is the value of `n`?

Comment: Look at the first term.  -1 ^ (n-i).  Start with 1.  What is -1^1?  How about -1^2?  -1^3?  -1^4?  Starting to notice a pattern?  If not keep going, you'll see it.  There are much faster ways to figure out that answer than using the pow function once you notice the pattern.

Comment: Delta_G's pointing you in the right direction, but for future reference, `pow` can get expensive. A lot of compilers and Standard Library implementations are smart enough to take short cuts these days, but when they can't, your simple integer exponents will go down the same path used to compute the really nasty stuff like e to the power of pi. That's really slow. Plus it uses floating point math and can give imprecise results. Instead of a nice 10, you could wind up with a not-so-nice 9.9999999 that turns into 9 when you stuff the result into an integer. Multiplication is safer and better.

Comment: @Delta_G I tried removing "-pow(-1.0,(n-i)) " part and used something else instead which decreased the execution time but now when I input number approx. greater than 50 the output starts to come -291172004 ??

Comment: What you changed it to must have been the wrong thing.  Hard to tell since I can't see it.

Comment: `ps: This formula is for the following proble` decide - one question per question. Either you ask one or the other.

Comment: @KamilCuk I gave the link just in case someone wanted to know where the formula came from...I didn't ask to solve the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Each member of the series is given as, with `i` as the index:

```
s_i = - (-1)^i * 3^(n-i) =
    = - (-1)^i * 3^n * 3^(-i) =
    = - 3^n * (-1)^i * 3^(-i) =
    = - 3^n * (-1)^i * 1 / (3^i) =
    = - 3^n * (-1/3)^i
```

This is a geometric series and a [sum of first `n` elements geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) is:

```
a = -3^n
r = -1/3
sum = a * (( 1 - r^n ) / ( 1 - r ))
```

Just compute it:

```
const double a = -pow(3.0, n)
const double r = -1.0/3.0;
const double ans = a * (( 1.0 - pow(r, n) ) / ( 1.0 - r ));
```

Aaand that's not all because we are summing the sum from the first `k=1` element  not the zero element, so the result is not correct, which is left to the reader to find out what has to be done and correct...

**Do not skip school**.

Comment: I did notice it was a gp....it was just that I wanted to avoid using the pow function as it was increasing execution time, I was asking for some alternate faster way without using pow.

Comment: and also the constraint on the output was that it had to be an int, so I avoided using this as it gives output in double.

Comment: The exponent in `pow` is an int - just implement your own something along `int powi(int x, int b) { int r = x; while (b--) r*=x; return r; }` to not to use floating points.

Comment: I know that but this still takes up execution time....I was asking for an alternate way to do this....and thank u for ur helpful comment at the end of the answer I'll stop skipping school from nowonwards